# How does Magento manage the payment for the ordered products with Paypal?

Tags: magento, soap, paypal, magento-1.7

Good morning!

I’m developing a mobile app for a Magento store (for Android). I’m using SOAP v1 and I’ve made a custom module with some custom methods. The app it’s focused to the final client, so, basically, I’m developing an app that lets the costumers buy products from the store. 
I know how to add with the Magento API the products to the cart and how to make an order, but…

**What happens when I create the order?**

```
call($sessionId,"cart.order",array($shoppingCartId, null, $licenseForOrderCreation));
```

It’s supposed that the costumer has to pay the products that he ordered, so I don’t know how can I get the Paypal URL and open it in the browser. **Paypal notifies to the Magento store that the costumer paid the products?**

I’m a bit lost in this area.
The API documentation doesn’t explain this part, I think.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to do the same. I'm thinking to use the current Paypal SDKs to do the entire payment and somehow send the payment ID to the server via SOAP for order fulfillment, but I don't know if this is going to work. Given the time since you asked this question maybe you've find a solution, do you?

Comment: I haven't found any solution, sorry. Magento documentation really sucks. I was stuck in that project, so now I'm not working on it. Anyway, if you find any way to make it work, I'll be really grateful if you could contact with me. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering anyway, give it for sure that if I find a way to do this I'll share it here with you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using paypal_standard as your payment method. Then follow these steps.

1. Place order using payment method as paypal_standard.
2. After that initiate payment through paypal standard sdk.
3. after successful payment you can create your own api and through which you can edit previously created order using below code.

   ```
   $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton("core/app_emulation");
   $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);
   $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
   $payment = $order->getPayment();
   $payment->setTransactionId($confirm->response->id)
               ->setPreparedMessage("status : ".$confirm->response->state)
               ->setShouldCloseParentTransaction(true)
               ->setIsTransactionClosed(0)
               ->registerCaptureNotification($order->getGrandTotal());
   $order->save();
   if($status == 0){
       $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
           ->setStatus(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
           ->save();
   }
   else{
       $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)
           ->setStatus(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)
           ->save();
   }
   if($order->canInvoice()){
       $invoice = Mage::getModel("sales/service_order", $order)->prepareInvoice();
       $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
       $invoice->register();
       $transactionSave = Mage::getModel("core/resource_transaction")
           ->addObject($invoice)
           ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
       $transactionSave->save();
   }
   $comment = "status :".$confirm->response->state."<br>";
   $comment .= "transaction id :".$confirm->response->id."<br>";
   $comment .= "date :".$confirm->response->create_time."<br>";
   $comment .= "from :".$confirm->client->product_name."<br>";
   $order->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
   $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment);
   $order->save();
   $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
   ```